# Tmux wait for detach?

Tags: tmux

I'm looking for a way to wait execution then detach from current tmux session through bash command line.

For example currently I'm trying to build a deployment automation command line tool. It should does:

- create a new tmux session, attache to it,
- run a file (e.g. build) showing user its stdout,
- **when its execution ends** detach from the session,
- and capture-pane to if the stdout is finished in a success way or an error way then if it's success is true continues to the next file (e.g. launch) and showing user its stdout creating and attaching to a new tmux session, and so on.

I tried the followings, however it didn't work as it doesn't wait for the previous commands but immediately detaches. (Note: assume the build.sh takes tens of seconds to execute with its stdout)

```sh
tmux a -t tmp \; \
    set-buffer ". /root/pg/myapp/production/.deploy/remote/build.sh;" \; paste-buffer \; send-keys C-m \; \
    set-buffer "tmux wait-for -S done;" \; paste-buffer \; send-keys C-m \; \
    set-buffer "tmux wait-for done;" \; paste-buffer \; send-keys C-m \; \
    detach \;
```

```sh
tmux a -t tmp \; \
    set-buffer ". /root/pg/myapp/production/.deploy/remote/build.sh;" \; paste-buffer \; send-keys C-m \; \
    send-keys C-b \; \
    send-keys d \;
```

versions:

```
# tmux -V
tmux 3.0a

# bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

Thanks.

Comment: To be honest, that second paragraph with your "flow" is a bit hard to follow.  I might suggest breaking that out into bullet points for clarity.

Comment: fixed. thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue by the following:

```
tmux a -t tmp \; \
            set-buffer "sleep 1;" \; paste-buffer \; send-keys C-m \; \
            set-buffer "tmux detach;" \; paste-buffer \; send-keys C-m \;
```

Simply use `tmux detach` bash command instead of `detach` tmux command.